# CR to LF/CR when inserting in MS Access

Tags: java, database

I have a java program which scrapes data from a PDF Form (via PDFBox) and then into a MS Access Database (via Ucanaccess).

A large text string is inserted into a MS Access Long Text field, but I am losing all the line breaks.

Coming from the PDF only seems to be \r (CR) and copying data from the database shows CR+LF.

I assume this is the whole linux/windows thing and basically I should do a replace line like

```
pdf.get(c).replaceAll("\r", "\r\n");
```

Where pdf is a hashmap and c at somepoint will pull the string containing the memo field.

Cheers

Al

Comment: And what is your question?

Comment: If it works using the `replaceAll`, you might give the method `PDFTextStripper.setLineSeparator(String)` a try.

Comment: Try the ASCII equivalents of carriage returns and line breaks: `Chr(10)` and `Chr(13)`.